# Run cdklocal in AWS CodeBuild. Error: no credentials have been configured

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codebuild, localstack

#### My Setup

I have a typescript CDK Project which deploys several lambdas to AWS using a CDK pipeline.

I am using [aws-cdk-local](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-cdk-local) and [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) to run some tests in a codebuild action in a CDK pipeline. I want to do this so I can create a local dynamodb stack to run my tests against in the pipeline (before deployment of the real stack).

#### My Problem

This works fine on my own PC but I am getting the following error from codebuild when I run `cdklocal bootstrap` and `cdklocal deploy` from my codebuild action.

```
Environment aws://000000000000/ap-southeast-1 failed bootstrapping: Error: Need to perform AWS calls for account 000000000000, but no credentials have been configured.
```

Here is a screenshot [image: screenshot]

You can see I even tried setting mock credentials but it didn't help.

Am I missing something?

Has anyone had success running `cdklocal` from AWS Codebuild?

Thanks :)

For completeness [here](https://github.com/ziggy6792/cdk-monorepo-example-backend/tree/feature/new-test-env) is my code

Answer (score 0):

Problem was I wasn't starting localstack before bootstrapping.